# Remove overflow menu 3 dots in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-toolbar

I have a fragment that needs to have a custom menu. Below is the code which is added to my fragment.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
```

My `actionbar_menu` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction" />
</menu>
```

I only want this search icon to be present in the toolbar. What happens is its adding overflow menu too. How can I remove the overflow menu?

**UPDATE:** I am getting this issue only in mobiles. In tablet emulators its not showing up.

Comment: Are you adding Menu in Activity Also or in another fragment ? Because this code won't be showing a Overflow menu ..

Comment: @ADM I am adding the menu to the fragment present in my activity

Comment: Use `withText` instead of `always` in `showAsAction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I called the same in different way.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    menu.clear()
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove menu inflate override functions from fragment container activity.

Fragment class:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(false)         // Show/Hide Icon
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)    // Give your desire menu.xml
}
```

This function can show/hide overflow menu icon setHasOptionsMenu()

- If you use setHasOptionsMenu(true), then menu icon is appeared on toolbar.
- else setHasOptionsMenu(false), then menu icon is hidden on toolbar.